# Controlling library_names and dlname config vars in .la file during build process

Tags: makefile, libtool

In a given build flow (which I wasn't involved with) that includes a few libraries, the `make` command generates an .la file, where the .so numbering is always 0 and 0.0.0 (i.e. `dlname='libFoo.so.0'` and  `library_names='libFoo.so.0.0.0 libFoo.so.0 libFoo.so'`).

The .la file is created during the process, so I can't modify it directly. What's the input configuration file for .la, and which values should I change in order to control the version numbering? Thanks.

Comment: I found a solution: in the .am file I added to the variable ``libFoo_la_LDFLAGS`` the flag ``-version-number 1:2:3``. This variable is passed in the compiled Makefile to the variable libFoo_la_LINK, which is part of the ``libFoo.la: `` definition.

Comment: I'm also struggling with this problem. Mine always gives 7.0.1.

Comment: FYI, the .so number is called _soname_.